# On request Kafka stream processing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two topics and want to join them once a request comes. 
e.g. Topic A for students and B for departments. When my application ask for join I will create a stream and send the result back to application.

I have few doubts

1- is Kafka streams are meant for this type of on-demand processing?

2- How to close stream once request is complete?

3- Can we achieve it by storm or sambza?

Any other suggestion for this use case.

Comment: What do you mean "once a request comes"?  Once a new message/event arrives at one of the two input topics?

Comment: I mean I don't want my kafka stream to continuously listening and processing to topics. stream should join and provide the result once a request for same comes.

Comment: But if Streams is not running (ie, not listening -- or actually not polling -- note, Kafka uses a pull model) how should the application know that there is now data? Stream processing applications in general run continuously. And they also continuously produce output as long as they are running and new data arrives. Thus, you should design you application to continuously computes the current result and if you application ask for the result you just serve it. If you want to do something else, it's not Stream processing and not of the tools you mentioned will provide what you describe.

Comment: That is my understanding too about streams. So if I do this preprocessing and put the processed data in topic. How will I query it for a perticular record and what will be the best way to query it in terms of performance.

Comment: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#interactive-queries